# iPhone: Is there any way to execute iPhone func like camara frome web app

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I just start to develop web app for iPhone with jQtuch..and its fun!

Q: is there some way to invoke some iPhone func like capturing image
from the web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the browser is strictly limited to web applications and is sandboxed in the same way your browser on your computer can't access anything.